# Print Column Names in Oracle SQLDeveloper

Tags: printing, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I print my table on paper, I want the column names to show. I'm currently getting:

[image]

**How can I display the column names on paper?**

Comment: It doesn't look like you can, which seems like a weird omission. (I'm not sure what the benefit of the %COLUMN% option is either). I guess you'd need to export as CSV and print from Excel/Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the worksheet

Type and run
  SELECT * FROM GAME

In the results, click the 'print' button in the grid toolbar.

[image]

If you don't want to leave the table/view editor where you're at, just use the right-click, export feature, and print to file, then open said file and print from there.